# CSS doesn't work for some reason

Tags: css, linux, firefox, chromium

So I have stumbled upon this problem, CSS just doesn't work on my computer, and what is more interesting, it doesn't work only for files that I create and it doesn't work only for me. So when I go to any webpage, CSS will work perfectly, however when I go to websites created by me, it wont work only for me, but it will work for other people. 
Things I've done so far:

- Tested other browsers (didn't work on chromium and firefox)
- Checked from other computers (CSS worked on them)
- Told other ppl to check it(worked for them)
- Some people said that it might be because of adblock, disabled it
  everywhere, still no results.

I have Linux Mint 15, and I either suspect that it might be something to do with either my OS or the way I save files, but I'm clueless of what to do to be honest, I've never had a problem like this before.

Comment: Try the old "clear your cache" thing.

Comment: http://noashy.com/portfolio/custom_blog_2/
For me it's just white page, and a vertical bullet point list with icons.

Comment: Well, that's the point, it doesn't work just fine for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link to your stylesheet is bad. Stylesheets have type `text/css`.

Solution: change `type="style/css"` to `type="text/css"`.

There are other errors in your page as well, such as the missing `>` after `<ul`, so you should validate your source, for instance with the [W3C Validator](http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fnoashy.com%2Fportfolio%2Fcustom_blog_2%2F&charset=%28detect+automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0). But the above one is the problem you're after.